# How annotations are being scanned in a spring boot application internally and post processors works?

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, classloader

I am creating an application based on some custom annotations and I feel the need to validate my whole application that whether there is any class annotated with the same annotations.

I created a PostProcessors as per existing Spring Post Processor but not able to see how i can include the same post processor while loading my application as my Post Processor is in a JAR file.

I wanted to know how existing post processors are included to get the annotated classes validated since my class is in a separate jar not in the application in which i need to use it...

Comment: How does your JAR file look like? Do you have a configuration class or just a class with @Component?

Comment: I have compiled a normal java project as jar and prepare the PostProcessors as per spring ones but not able to use annotations inside of my jar as none was scanned but i want my validations to be incorporated at build up of any project that include my jar.